# What is this rhetorical scheme or literary device called?

Tags: literary-device, rhetorical-devices

I can't recall the name of the rhetorical scheme or literary device involved with using the same word more than once within the same sentence but with different meanings:

"The only thing we have to fear is fear itself."

- fear - verb
- fear - noun

"Turn right right here."

- right - adv. directional
- right - adv. in this place

"My feet are but feet away."

- feet - noun lower appendage
- feet - noun distance

Comment: This is a list of [Shakespeare's literary devices](https://quizlet.com/12349692/shakespeare-literary-devices-and-terms-flash-cards/). The only one that comes close to what you are describing is a *pun*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you mean *antanaclasis*:

> The repetition of a word or phrase whose meaning changes in the second instance.

From [*Silva Rhetoricae*, "antanaclasis"](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/antanaclasis.htm).

Some examples from that site:

> Your argument is sound...all sound. —Benjamin Franklin
>   If you aren't fired with enthusiasm, you will be fired with enthusiasm. —Vince Lombardi

(op. cit.)

The overarching figure for such repetition in brief sentences is *paregmenon*:

> A general term for the repetition of a word or its cognates in a short sentence.

*Polyptoton* (as in your first example), is also a possibility:

> Repeating a word, but in a different form. Using a cognate of a given word in close proximity.

*Adnominatio* is sometimes used as a synonym of *polyptoton*.

*Antistasis*,

> The repetition of a word in a contrary sense.

is sometimes used as a synonym of *antanaclasis*.

(All definitions from [*Silva Rhetoricae*](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/).)

Comment: Antanaclasis!!!!  Woohooo!!  I knew it when I saw it!  Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you.  My brain was hurting trying to remember it.  I had paged though no less than 50 schemes and I couldn't find it.  Ugh!  What a load off!

Comment: Thank you for that information.  I'm going to go read up on those.

Comment: Also closely related, syllepsis, zeugma, and the pun.