# What would we call this literary device?

Tags: sentence-patterns, literary-device, poetic-devices

To best describe it, when the same word or family of words is used twice in the same sentence to provide an ironic meaning. For instance, "raiding English from the English, stealing poetry from the poets".

Comment: In the general sense, I’d say relying on the ambiguity of polysemy us words to create a rhetorical impact a “pun”, though that’s a broader concept that the specific use of repetition you point to here.

Comment: If it is the same word, you can call it 'antanaclasis'; if it is words with the same root, you can call it 'polyptoton.'

Comment: Similar question: [What is this rhetorical scheme or literary device called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298851/what-is-this-rhetorical-scheme-or-literary-device-called)

Answer (score 2):

The literary device you are referring to is called ***[Repetition](https://literarydevices.net/repetition/)*** :

> a literary device that involves intentionally using a word or phrase for effect, two or more times in a speech or written work. For repetition to be noticeable, the words or phrases should be repeated within close proximity of each other.

(literarydevices.net